# Do photons slow down this much in the Sun's gravitational field?

Tags: photons, astrophysics, sun, mean-free-path

I just heard someone mention that photons take 40 thousand years to travel from the centre of the Sun to its
surface which is roughly 700,000 kilometres. How is that possible  if the speed of light/photons is 300,000 km/second?

Comment: related/possible duplicate: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/103987/50583, https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/352979/50583

Comment: It has nothing to do with gravity - they just bounce around.

Comment: I once estimated the time for a given bit of energy to escape the Sun using the Sun's total thermal energy and the Sun's luminosity.  I got an answer of 26 million years.  Others commented that my methodology was no good, but I never understood their reasoning.  The thread is at the following link if anyone would care to see my method.  Thanks!  https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/364765/another-way-to-find-the-energy-diffusion-time-in-the-sun

Comment: As a quantitative aspect to every answer saying "gravity plays no large role", I calculated (plugging $d\theta=d\phi=d\tau=0$ into the [interior Schwarzschild metric](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interior_Schwarzschild_metric) and integrating to find the change in coordinate time $t$ for a path from $r=0$ to $r=r_g$) that light from the very center of the sun would take approx. 3.28 seconds to reach the surface of the sun (if it didn't get absorbed), which is about 41.4% longer than if the sun had no mass. Measurable? Maybe. But it's not the main delay.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Light formed by the sun?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/103987/)

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Photons (as electromagnetic waves) always travel at the speed of light (in a vacuum and in this case between particle collisions - see below) which is about $\approx 3 \times 10^8 \ \text{ms}^{-1}$. They are being "slowed down", but not the way you think and not because of the suns' gravitational field, of which this has nothing to do with.

More precisely, although the photons travel from the core to the photosphere, which is a certain distance, the path they take is not direct.

Because the sun is dense, a photon emitted at the core will be absorbed by another nearby proton almost immediately, and then that proton will vibrate and re-emit another in a random direction. This happens over and over again *many* times so that when it reaches the sun's surface, thousands of years have passed.
This process is described by what is called a [random walk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_walk).

The distance that a photon can travel before it is absorbed, is given by what's called the
[mean free path](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_free_path), given by the equation

$$l = \frac{1}{\sigma n}$$

*"where $n$ is the number of target particles per unit volume, and $\sigma$ is the effective cross-sectional area for collision."*

As you can appreciate, the number of target particles (protons) will be significantly high making the mean free path extremely small, so the number of collisions is significantly high. in other words, the photon travels a substantial distance from the Suns' core to its surface, which takes thousands of years. After which it takes a measly 9 minutes to reach us,

$^1$ Also be careful with terms like "same" photon, since elementary particles (of a particular type) are *indistinguishable* (even in principle), so to give any particle a specific *identity* is technically incorrect. See [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identical_particles) article about identical particles.

Comment: "are not the "same" photon", but in the statistical models that give us the time it takes to reach the surface,  it is "assumed" to be the same photon. In truth it is  energy carried  over by the virtual photons in the zillions of interactions that reaches the surface of the sun after a long time.

Comment: Yeah but it isn’t though is it? I think this point should be made since the OP was of the opinion that an emitted photon travels from the centre to the outside unimpeded.

Comment: a) Wouldn't the photons scatter of both protons and electrons (and the occasional helium or deuterium core). b) I don't think "the proton will vibrate" is a very accurate description in a plasma as there are no "vibrational" degrees of freedom.

Comment: @Drjh The language doesn't really work well for quanta. Photons (just like electrons etc.) do not have identity; "the same photon" is essentially meaningless as soon as you lose the ability to factorize "individual" photons. But we can definitely say some interesting things about the "photon emitted from a fusion reaction in the Sun's core" and "photon emitted from the photosphere" - most obviously, they have very different energies, random direction and there's many more "photosphere photons" than there are "fusion photons" (so there's definitely no 1:1 relationship).

Comment: @Drjh I think saying "mostly protons" is quite wrong. Consider the stellar opacity model in https://arxiv.org/abs/1601.01930 Photon-proton scattering is not considered at all. Perhaps you're thinking of free-free scattering from unbound proton-electron dipoles?

Comment: There's a real danger with answers like this.  The correct answer *to the question asked* would be "Ah, the 40,000 years you heard about has absolutely nothing to do with gravity as you ask in your question. It's a totally unrelated effect."  One could certainly then *go on* to explain (as in this superbly-written answer), that other effect.  But the actual answer to the question is "it has nothing to do with that".

Comment: No, the sun is not extremely dense. The conditions at the center of the sun are quite extreme in terms of pressure and temperature, and the density is quite impressive if one takes into account that the sun is made up mainly of hydrogen (plasma) which under "normal" conditions has a very low density, but in absolute terms the sun has a low density. Indeed the moon has about three times the density of the sun, a fact that, given the curious coincidence that sun and moon disks have almost exactly the same size as seen from the earth, explains why the moon has more tidal effect than the sun has.

Comment: How much time elapses between a particle absorbing the photon, then emitting a "new" one? That is, how much of the 40,000 years is due to the length of the actual path travelled, and how much due is spent "stopping" at all the particles along the way?

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen isn't the increased tidal effect more a result of gravity's strength being inversely proportional to the square of distance between two objects?

Comment: @TCooper No, since if that were true the sun would easily beat the moon, as it is $p$ times as far away, $p$ times the linear size, and so $p^3$ times as voluminous, for some large factor $p$ of proportionality (I guess around $300$, thought I'd need to check the numbers). However tidal effect is proportional to the _derivative_ of the vector-valued gravitational strength (or more properly acceleration), which follows an inverse _cube_ law. That precisely cancels the volume effect, so only density remains.

Comment: That's very interesting. Frankly I don't follow and will have to read up, so thank you for sharing. I was just referencing some old grade school knowledge... I always understood gravity as a relationship of *mass* and distance. Not accounting for volume or density at all (highly simplified) though I did find this: https://oceanservice.noaa.gov/education/tutorial_tides/tides02_cause.html Is it simply a case of the noaa needing to update their website?

Comment: @Tcooper that would be a good question to submit to this site.

Comment: @TCooper The NOAA’s website looks OK to me; I think it just has a different way of explaining things. Further discussion at this question: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/595071/in-the-difference-between-the-sun-and-moons-tidal-effects-on-earth-is-density

Comment: Do you mean the photons travel at the vacuum speed of light between particle collisions? That is not clear from how it is written. Can you rephrase to make it more clear?

Comment: @TCooper.  The dependency of tidal effects on the derivative of the gravitational force function with distance can be understood by realizing the tidal effect depends on the difference in the gravitational effects experienced on the near and back sides of the Earth.  It's the rate of change of gravity over the distance subtended by the Earth's diameter that matters.

Comment: How is the time to exit the sun measured?

Comment: @JThomas It isn't really _measured_ as such, but the models we have in particle and plasma/etc., physics provides us with accurate numbers. Thanks.

Answer (score 8):

Gravity has little to do with it.  The sun is a dense plasma and particles of plasma  prolifically scatter photons (both elastically and inelastically). Hence the photon does not travel from the center to the surface in a straight line.

Answer (score 1):

I should to clarify that gravitational field changes the wavelength of light (consequently the momentum of the photon in the vacuum) but not the speed of the photon since $$ p = \frac{\hbar}{\lambda} $$ and the speed of light in the vacuum remains absolute according to the relativity principle.

The reason of the apparent slow down of the speed of light in the sun is explained extensively in the previous answers.

Comment: Sure the speed of light in vacuum is always the same _locally_, but difference between frames of reference in different gravitational fields makes up for a _total_ difference in speed. Not that this is the case with the sun, but light from a very dense neutron star can be significantly Shapiro delayed from the time it leaves the surface until it reaches a far away observer.

Comment: Yes Shapiro delay can be measured for rays passing closely by the sun but it should be negligible in front of the scattering effect. Thank you @Ivella

Answer (score 1):

The energy produced in the core takes that long to reach the surface.  It's not the same photon taking that long.  Photons are constantly emitted and absorbed, and the energy also spends time as kinetic energy of the electrons and protons in the plasma.

The core gets hot.  It takes 40k years (or whatever the correct number may be) for it to *cool*, working its way though the entire bulk of the sun's material.

Comment: What is "it" in *"...40k years (or whatever the correct number may be) for it to cool"*? An individual molecule that happens to be in the core? A photon starting out in the core (as a result of fusion)? Something else? It can not be the core itself.

Comment: Yes, the core itself.  That's how long it takes energy to reach the surface.